# Cognitive impairment in long term prisoners

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Are there any studies on the effects of long term imprisonment on cognitive abilities? I'm looking for something which focuses on cognitive impairment rather than other psychological issues.

Comment: Any motivation on why you are asking this question? On what is your assumption for a correlation between the two based?